# Delete mobile margin on Wordpress-Elementor

Tags: wordpress, mobile, margin, elementor

I have my website with Wordpress and Elementor, but on some mobile devices there is a margin that is not from Elementor sections and I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried some settings on CSS, I've got a code that works when you previsualize mobile display on Elementor and it worked but it doesn't work when you previsualize the website on google with some devices.

[image: It is the blue margin in the right side]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code in your defined class or id for the remove Margin on the mobile device.

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.classname {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```